# Update alreade printed text with new value of variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

Imagine the following structure. A global variable and simple text printed.

```
var 2BPrinted = 0;
$('body').append('<div class="message">Something </div>' + 2BPrinted);
```

Then a large function with one click structure `$('elem'.one("click", function){...})` where the 2BPrinted is being repeatedly changed. I want to somehow parse those changes to the initially printed text, as it is not supposed to move anywhere, disappear or duplicate itself. I'm not completely sure, that what I want is possible, however I use Jquery (You might want to know).

Probably another way of achieving it would be, If I print the text every time the variable is being changed (every click), but I need to get rid of the old one at the same time. Any suggestions?

Comment: If the variable is being changed on each click, at the end of the click function run a function to update the text. I suggest you take a look at the .html() method for how to do this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Separate the text in its own element when rendering it initially and then change the content of that element when the variable changes its value in your click function. Something like this:

```
var 2BPrinted = 0;
$('body').append('<div class="message">Something </div>' + 
    '<div id="contentContainer">' + 2BPrinted + '</div>');

$('elem'.one("click", function){
    // your logic runs and changes 2BPrinted
    $("#contentContainer").text(2BPrinted);
})
```

Comment: Great advice! Thanks, it perfectly solves the problem